# Cross compiler GCC keeps failing to compile on macOS

Tags: c, macos, gcc, cross-compiling

I am on my journey to building an kernel/OS. Up to this point I have used a precompiled version of GCC I got from Homebrew. In an effort to do this project properly, I am trying to move to a cross compiler with an elf target and no headers (following the OSDev tutorial). When I compile GCC I keep getting this error when it ends

```
    /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ../../gcc-11.3.0/gcc/tsan.h /opt/cross/lib/gcc/x86_64-elf/11.3.0/plugin/include/tsan.h
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ../../gcc-11.3.0/gcc/tsystem.h /opt/cross/lib/gcc/x86_64-elf/11.3.0/plugin/include/tsystem.h
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ../../gcc-11.3.0/gcc/typeclass.h /opt/cross/lib/gcc/x86_64-elf/11.3.0/plugin/include/typeclass.h
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ../../gcc-11.3.0/gcc/typed-splay-tree.h /opt/cross/lib/gcc/x86_64-elf/11.3.0/plugin/include/typed-splay-tree.h
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ../../gcc-11.3.0/gcc/ubsan.h /opt/cross/lib/gcc/x86_64-elf/11.3.0/plugin/include/ubsan.h
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ../../gcc-11.3.0/gcc/valtrack.h /opt/cross/lib/gcc/x86_64-elf/11.3.0/plugin/include/valtrack.h
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ../../gcc-11.3.0/gcc/value-prof.h /opt/cross/lib/gcc/x86_64-elf/11.3.0/plugin/include/value-prof.h
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ../../gcc-11.3.0/gcc/value-query.h /opt/cross/lib/gcc/x86_64-elf/11.3.0/plugin/include/value-query.h
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ../../gcc-11.3.0/gcc/value-range-equiv.h /opt/cross/lib/gcc/x86_64-elf/11.3.0/plugin/include/value-range-equiv.h
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ../../gcc-11.3.0/gcc/value-range.h /opt/cross/lib/gcc/x86_64-elf/11.3.0/plugin/include/value-range.h
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ../../gcc-11.3.0/gcc/varasm.h /opt/cross/lib/gcc/x86_64-elf/11.3.0/plugin/include/varasm.h
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ../../gcc-11.3.0/gcc/vec-perm-indices.h /opt/cross/lib/gcc/x86_64-elf/11.3.0/plugin/include/vec-perm-indices.h
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ../../gcc-11.3.0/gcc/vec.h /opt/cross/lib/gcc/x86_64-elf/11.3.0/plugin/include/vec.h
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ../../gcc-11.3.0/gcc/vector-builder.h /opt/cross/lib/gcc/x86_64-elf/11.3.0/plugin/include/vector-builder.h
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ../../gcc-11.3.0/gcc/version.h /opt/cross/lib/gcc/x86_64-elf/11.3.0/plugin/include/version.h
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ../../gcc-11.3.0/gcc/vmsdbg.h /opt/cross/lib/gcc/x86_64-elf/11.3.0/plugin/include/vmsdbg.h
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ../../gcc-11.3.0/gcc/vr-values.h /opt/cross/lib/gcc/x86_64-elf/11.3.0/plugin/include/vr-values.h
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ../../gcc-11.3.0/gcc/vtable-verify.h /opt/cross/lib/gcc/x86_64-elf/11.3.0/plugin/include/vtable-verify.h
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ../../gcc-11.3.0/gcc/wide-int-bitmask.h /opt/cross/lib/gcc/x86_64-elf/11.3.0/plugin/include/wide-int-bitmask.h
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ../../gcc-11.3.0/gcc/wide-int-print.h /opt/cross/lib/gcc/x86_64-elf/11.3.0/plugin/include/wide-int-print.h
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ../../gcc-11.3.0/gcc/wide-int.h /opt/cross/lib/gcc/x86_64-elf/11.3.0/plugin/include/wide-int.h
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ../../gcc-11.3.0/gcc/xcoff.h /opt/cross/lib/gcc/x86_64-elf/11.3.0/plugin/include/xcoff.h
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ../../gcc-11.3.0/gcc/xcoffout.h /opt/cross/lib/gcc/x86_64-elf/11.3.0/plugin/include/xcoffout.h
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 b-header-vars /opt/cross/lib/gcc/x86_64-elf/11.3.0/plugin/include/b-header-vars
/bin/sh ../gcc-11.3.0/mkinstalldirs /opt/cross /opt/cross
/bin/sh ../../../gcc-11.3.0/libgcc/../mkinstalldirs /opt/cross/lib/gcc/x86_64-elf/11.3.0
/bin/sh ../../../gcc-11.3.0/libgcc/../mkinstalldirs /opt/cross/lib/gcc/x86_64-elf/11.3.0/include
/bin/sh ../../../gcc-11.3.0/libgcc/../mkinstalldirs /opt/cross/lib/gcc/x86_64-elf/11.3.0/include
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 libgcc.a /opt/cross/lib/gcc/x86_64-elf/11.3.0/
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 unwind.h /opt/cross/lib/gcc/x86_64-elf/11.3.0/include
install: libgcc.a: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [install-leaf] Error 71
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ../../../gcc-11.3.0/libgcc/gcov.h /opt/cross/lib/gcc/x86_64-elf/11.3.0/include
make: *** [install-target-libgcc] Error 2
```

I scrolled up on the logs and found this:

```
    In file included from ../../../gcc-11.3.0/libgcc/libgcov-merge.c:26:
../../../gcc-11.3.0/libgcc/libgcov.h:49:10: fatal error: sys/mman.h: No such file or directory
   49 | #include <sys/mman.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [_gcov_merge_add.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
In file included from ../../../gcc-11.3.0/libgcc/libgcov-merge.c:26:
../../../gcc-11.3.0/libgcc/libgcov.h:49:10: fatal error: sys/mman.h: No such file or directory
   49 | #include <sys/mman.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [_gcov_merge_topn.o] Error 1
In file included from ../../../gcc-11.3.0/libgcc/libgcov-merge.c:26:
../../../gcc-11.3.0/libgcc/libgcov.h:49:10: fatal error: sys/mman.h: No such file or directory
   49 | #include <sys/mman.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [_gcov_merge_ior.o] Error 1
make: *** [all-target-libgcc] Error 2
```

The thing is that sys/mman.h does exist in the MacOSX.sdk folder, which is preconfigured as my compilers system root (using GCC 11.3.0 from Homebrew). I also made sure that GCC had all its dependencies in the root of the source folder. In a step to isolate other factors I created a fresh macOS VM, installed all the necessary tools and tried to build but got the same errors.  My system is an iMac 27 inch (9900K) running macOS 12.6

Comment: So, some software which you downloaded as source fails to build. That's something for a bug ticket, not for SO, I would say.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I thought it'd be wiser to assume I'm doing something wrong/missing something rather than blame GCC (especially considering that I'm new to this)

Comment: It appears to be an issue with the standard library installation, not with gcc as such.

Comment: @Lundin Is there a way I can fix the library installation?

Comment: Probably, but I personally have no idea how to do that on a Mac, sorry. Though it's usually as easy as downloading the whole thing again and overwrite all files.